# Calling jQuery $ function on 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, why is it necessary to surround 'this' with the $ function?

```
var x = $('div');
x.click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

doesn't 'this' just refer to the expression x which is itself a jQuery object?

Comment: No, it doesn't. In the event handler, it will be a reference to the particular DOM element that is the target of the "click" event.

Comment: in the context of the event handler, 'this' is the actual DOM element that the handler triggered on.

Comment: You can't call a jQuery function on a non-jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No : `this` is the unwrapped DOM element, as specified in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) :

> The handler parameter takes a callback function, as shown above.
>   Within the handler, the keyword this refers to the DOM element to
>   which the handler is bound. To make use of the element in jQuery, it
>   can be passed to the normal $() function.

Answer (score 5):

The value of `this` will be the DOM node representing the clicked element. `$(this)` will be a jQuery object wrapping that DOM node, and providing extra functions like `.show()`, `.append()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this reffers div ...  thats mean that your div will hide when you click in it.

this always reffers what its in context.